# Android unresolved dependencies after upgrading Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm experiencing with unresolved dependency issue. I know there are multiple factors that can result to unresolved dependencies but this one seems a bit odd. I was using firebase-messaging of version 11.8.0 and everything worked fine. but when i update to firebase-messaging latest version (17.1.0) i get multiple dependencies error. What is odd is I'm not using any of those dependencies that causes the errors. Also, the error includes both google gms library of version 17.1.0 while currently the latest google gms version in 15.0.1.

**What i have tried so far**
1. Install recommended Repository and sync project (failed since it could not fine google gms library of version 17.1.0)
2. adding those libraries but still i get same errors

I have attached a screenshot of the error and my list of my dependencies
thanks.

[image: Errors]

[image: My dependencies]

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: yes i did. it says it could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.0 as it is required by firebase-messaging 17.1.0
when i add it, it says "Failed to notify dependency resolution listener." but as i mentioned, google gms dependencies' latest version is 15.0.1

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) versions, there are no:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-task:17.0.1
```

And according to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) versions for Android, there are no:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.1
```

So wherever you find this dependencies in your code, remove them. There are no such dependencies at all.

If you need to use `Firebase Messaging` you should add in your code also the following line of code, which is now mandatory:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. As i mentioned that the errors are odd because of what you said. There are no such versions. Thing is I haven't used them at all. What i know is some libraries depends on others. one of the errors i got after cleaning the project is "could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.0 " and it said that it is required by firebase-messaging

Comment: Have you tried to create another clean project and use only `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1`?

Comment: yes. If i use a clean project then no errors are thrown.

Comment: So is your project now working using `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1`?

Comment: No its not... However, if i start a clean project it does. so im still trying to find what dependency is causing the conflict

Comment: If you create a new clean project, try to add only the dependencies that you use and add them one at the time. But for `Firebase Messaging` only those two are needed and will work perfectly fine. Keep me poested.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: well Alex... i created a new project and added the dependencies one by one and gradle successfully synced... so, its not clear what was causing the error